# jTable wrong Rownumber after navigate with up / down Keys

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, key-events

To get the selected row in a jTable, I used a MouseEvent (`MouseClicked`). That works fine and give me the correct rownumber after clicking into the table.

To navigate trough the jTable, I added a new Listener (`KeyPressed`). If I press the up key, the rownumber is **not** been increased. If I press the up key again, the rowcount will be updated, but it is the rowcount from previously.

```
private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_UP){
     System.out.println("Key UP" + jTable1.getSelectedRow()); 
    } 

    if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_DOWN){ 
    System.out.println("Key DOWN" + jTable1.getSelectedRow()); 
    }
}
```

This is the simple code. If I click into first row of table and press the down key, the output is "Key DOWN0". But the second row is selected and output should be "Key DOWN1".

Comment: On your key listener are you calling `int index = myTable.getSelectedRow()>0?myTable.getSelectedRow()-1:0;` and `myTable.setRowSelectionInterval(index, index);` to select the previous row? (or something similar).
Please include some code to provide a clearer idea of what you are currently doing, so we can identify the cause.

Comment: Have you tryed anything? Could you add a short executable code it is really hard to help you without ^^.

Comment: <code>private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_UP){ System.out.println("Key UP" + jTable1.getSelectedRow()); } if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_DOWN){ System.out.println("Key DOWN" + jTable1.getSelectedRow()); }</code> This is the simple code. If I click into first row of table and press the down key, the output is "Key DOWN0". But the second row is selected and output should be "Key DOWN1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get the selected row in a jTable, I used a MouseEvent
>   (MouseClicked). That works fine and give me the correct rownumber
>   after clicking into the table.
>
> To navigate trough the jTable, I added a new Listener (KeyPressed). If
>   I press the up key, the rownumber is not been increased. If I press
>   the up key again, the rowcount will be updated, but it is the rowcount
>   from previously

.

I think that you would need to

- add [ListSelectionListener to JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)
- change [ListSelectionMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

@mKorbel already posted the correct answer: don't use low-level listeners for semantic requirements - ListSelectionModel/-Event hides all the low-level knitty-gritty details :-)

The details:

- JTable's internals have keyBindings to the up/down keys which change the selection
- keyBindings are served *after* the listeners

So at the time of your application code seeing the event, the table didn't yet had the opportunity to react - what you are printing is the selection *before* its internal change (triggered by the bindings).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `KeyReleased` instead of `KeyPressed`